# Caching external downloads with Workbox

Tags: progressive-web-apps, gatsby, workbox

I'm working on a GatsbyJS site using gatsby-plugin-offline which is available at example.com and would like to make PDF files to which I link on example.com but are at download.example.com/example.pdf available offline. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I'm not 100% familiar with `gatsby-plugin-offline`'s configuration, but it looks like https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/#available-options describes a process for appending additional service worker logic to thee end of its default configuration:

```
plugins: [{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  options: {
    appendScript: require.resolve(`src/custom-sw-code.js`),
  },
}]
```

Then in `src/custom-sw-code.js`:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname.endsWith('.pdf'),
  // Use StaleWhileRevalidate, CacheFirst, etc. as desired.
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'pdfs'})
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It still does not seem to work for me. Neither your approach nor overriding the [Workbox config](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/#overriding-workbox-configuration) and adding a URL pattern for PDFs there caches them. Is the reason possibly that I am not embedding the PDFs on my site but just linking to them?